# Visual Studio debugging super slow with keyboard shortcuts, OK when pressing UI buttons...?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2015, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-debugging

I just reinstalled Windows 10 and everything.

When I am in break mode in Visual Studio, it is VERY slow most of the time (sometimes OK-ish). From 2 to 8 seconds for a step over. I checked pretty much every thread talking about slow VS debugging, nothing worked.

I noticed it works pretty fine when I click on the debug UI buttons (step over, step into etc) and actions are instant, just like it should be.

I'm pretty desperated, I hate slow computers and it's driving me crazy...
Would someone have an idea?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: affected commands are:

- step into
- step over
- continue
- add breakpoint
- remove breakpoint

Answer (score 0):

do one thing,

```
go to tools>>option>>IntelliTrace>> turn this off

close the visual studio and open>>build and run it
```

This is causing to make your application to run slow

Comment: As I said, I already tried most of classical solutions, disabling Intellitrace was one of the first things I tried. Plus, the application is not slow since it works fine when I click buttons.

Comment: what did you say , your question does not clarify anything, did you try what i said.. try before  if not you have minimum RAM and GHz speed on computer that what is making your computer slow.

Comment: I tried what you say and I tried 15 other tweaks. Nothing worked. My computer is not slow, only keyboard inputs.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Run VS in Safe mode(devenv/safemode) and close all third party tools in your windows, so we could know that whether it is not related to the add-ins or extension tools in your VS and windows. Run the keyboard short again.

(2) Since it works well using the button options directly, please make sure that it is not related to the hardware/drive. For example, using another keyboard or update the drive, check it again.

(3) I know that if we debug an app for the first time, sometimes it would be slow to load some symbols file or others, but if we debug it for the second time, it would be better, so please use the same debugging way like using the keyboard for two or more times, check it again.

Comment: I tried all your suggestions, did not help. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: Do you test it in other VS machine?

Comment: If you change the default keyboard shortcut, and custom a new one for it in your VS IDE, how about the result? Please also reset your VS settings, select another language settings as the default, test it again.